# MTA and TPL in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mta

I have a two fold question.

1.) I am using a third party library to build an application and it is all based in .NET so I am forced to use this(I usually develop in native C++). One of the methods I need to call says in the documentation

> This method must be called from a MTA thread. Create a separate reciever thread and use the method Thread.SetApartmentState() to set the apartment state to MTA before starting it.

From my understanding of COM and the threading models it is more about an objects ability to work in a MTA i.e. handles its own syncronizaton then needing to be in a MTA.

2.) I am intending to implement this in .NET 4.5 so I have been reading and seems like post 4.0 the suggestion is to use TPL more threading. Will this comply with or can I make it comply with the methods requirement to be in a MTA

Thanks
Matt

Comment: It makes little sense.  Any new Thread you create as well as any threadpool thread is already in the MTA by default so calling SetApartmentState() is superfluous.  Use a telephone instead of asking a stranger on the Internet.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but who should I have called??